# Action on clicking out of a form, inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

To start here is the fiddle with all the relevant code: http://jsfiddle.net/baruck/43787/
I'm building a webapp that at some point the user needs to register a number of items.
It is a big form, and this section of the form is inside a table.
Each input tag is inside a td followed by a span. When the user clicks to edit a certain row a script hides the span (that holds the value of the input) and shows up the input. When the user click on another row (or creates a new one) the script picks the value of the input add it/change the span text and hides the input and shows up the span.

When user clicks on some row, it first selects the row adding the 'editing' class to it, and the second click put the focus on the input.

While I'm clicking inside the table all goes well; the problem is when I click outside of the table that contains the inputs or hit tab after the last input on the active row. The focus go somewhere else...

When one of those two action happens I want to 'deactivate the row', meaning pick up the values from the inputs on that row, add/change them in the span, hide the input and show the span.

Summary: need to fire this function when clicking outside of the table with a class of 'editable' or when 'tab away' on the last input of row...

```
function deactivateRows() {
    //Deactivate editing on the rows
    $('table.editable tr.editing').removeClass('editing');
    $('table.editable').find('td').not('.delete').each(function () {
        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            var inputContent = $(this).val();
            $(this).prop('disabled', true).addClass('hide').attr('value', inputContent);
            $(this).parent().find('span').html(inputContent).removeClass('hide');
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the trick will be to traverse up the DOM from a clicked element, or the related element of a blur event, and see if you hit table.editable. Something like this:

```
var isInsideEditable = function (el) {
    return !!el && $(el).closest('table.editable').length > 0;
};

$('select, input, textarea', '.editable').on('blur', function (e) {
    if (!isInsideEditable(e.relatedTarget))
        deactivateRows();
});

$(window).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!isInsideEditable(e.target))
        deactivateRows();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Man, thanks a lot. It just worked. I've just add few more things to accomplish other functionalities (like delete empty rows)... but your suggestion worked just fine. The 'final version' can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/baruck/mk27e/

Comment: Great - glad it was useful.